# Enumerability of properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, enumerable

How to create non-enumerable properties at construction ?

```
function pp_urlfield( object ) {}
pp_urlfield.prototype = Object.create( Object.prototype, {
  type_internal: {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: ""
  },
  type: {
    get: function() {
      return this.type_internal;
    },
    set: function( value ) {
      this.type_internal = value;
    }
  }
} );
```

If I construct this object and assign the member "type", the assignment "this.type_internal = value" creates a local and non-enumerable variable :

```
var a = new pp_urlfield;
a.type = 1;
//Returns ["type_internal"]
Object.keys(a);
```

I found a partial solution by replacing this.type_internal = value by :

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "type_internal", { value: value, enumerable: false });
```

But I think there must be a better solution.
(I don't want to use any framework, e.g. Prototype)

Comment: its only possible in ECMA 5

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` is the only way (apart from `Object.create`) to specify non-enumerable properties. Of course you could wrap the call in a function to make it a bit simpler to use, but you won't be able to define non-enumerable properties in an object literal.

Comment: I can use ECMA 5 because it's a Chrome extension, for Chrome 28+. So if only defineProperty() can do it, what's the purpose of specifying enumerable: false at construction ?

Comment: @ehmicky: For before you write to it.